# Comparing two HTML files and return the HTML tags that differ between the two

Tags: python, html, difflib

I am writing a web monitoring script using python that will look at a archived version of the page, compare it to the current, online version, and notify me if there are any changes.  I have the basics of this working, but am running into a problem with sites that have a dynamic attribute in a web form.  The page in general hasn't changed, but a hidden attribute in the form has, which triggers a notification.

Using python's diflib on two HTML files with `diff = difflib.unified_diff(content1, content2)`, I am able to get the truncated output below.

```
-<input type='hidden' value='contact-us' name='ufo-form-pagename' id='ufo-form-pagename'/><input type='hidden' value='927eea55b8e87e961314033fce84de4a1418504077' name='ufo-sign' id='ufo-sign'/>

+<input type='hidden' value='contact-us' name='ufo-form-pagename' id='ufo-form-pagename'/><input type='hidden' value='1ccb910cbb9dc0d6f6dd5ed99212df741418800872' name='ufo-sign' id='ufo-sign'/>
```

I would like to 'read' through this output, and return the HTML attribute that do not have the same value, in this case `value='927eea55b8e87e961314033fce84de4a1418504077'`, and `value='1ccb910cbb9dc0d6f6dd5ed99212df741418800872'`

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

*I am writing a web monitoring script using python that will look at a archived version of the page, compare it to the current, online version, and notify me if there are any changes.*

Didn't you just answer your own question? If there's a diff then the file changed. :)

It sounds like what you want to do is ignore certain classes of changes. If you're not interested in properly parsing the HTML a naive hack could be to convert all whitespace to newlines and then run your diff. In this case the only difference you would see would be `value='927eea55...'` which you could have a regex pick up and ignore.

If you want to properly parse the HTML and do something more intelligent differencing, LMGTFY:

- https://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/
- https://github.com/fiduswriter/diffDOM

Comment: I have done that, but I need to see the difference, preferably just the offending attribute, and determine if it is significant or not.